# How to create master install folder with maven

Tags: maven-2, maven-assembly-plugin

Im trying to setup maven to assemble all my build artifacts into a central distribution folder.  to help with explainations, ive uploaded a sample project [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/05bf1m91yd2yafq/TestProject_package.zip)

This is a simple multi-module project with 2 j2ee components, each of those has a war, and ear sub-project.  If you comment out the assembly plugin in the top level pom, everything will build fine.

There is also an `outputFolder` which is how i want things to look when the assembling is all done.  Also in the `outputFolder` are misc jar files that will come from other sub-projects that just build a single jar (currently we have about 20 of these application jars).  Now since all the j2ee projects have the same directory structure and resulting distribution formats, I wanted to create a common assembly descriptor to be re-used across all of our j2ee components (currently theres about 15).

What I have so far does not work - in that it wont find the binary artifacts from any of the subprojects.  Ive tried using moduleSet and dependencySet sections in the assembly descriptor, but those dont seem to work either, i alwasy get something like: `The following patterns were never triggered in this artifact inclusion filter:  'myCompany:j2ee_A_ear:ear'`
Or if I try to put an assembly descriptor in the top level project, it causes wierd dependency errors when packaging my ear files.

Ive tried to use the dependency-copy plugin, but that seems to cause more problems than it solves.  Also others have said, the dependency plugin is the way to go for this.  Ive tried creating packaging only projects -- a sibling of the j2ee_A and j2ee_B projects in my example, but it cant seem to find any of the modules or dependencies

So im looking for an assembly descriptor (or descriptor **s**) that will be:
a) reusable across any number of j2ee sub-projects
b) also support single jar files
c) copy everything to a single folder

Ideas, suggestions and examples are welcome.